# Hibernate Insert Query value property using Dynamic Query -Annotations

Tags: hibernate

How to Implement below query in `Hibernate` using annotations.

```
INSERT INTO customers
  ( customer_id, firstname, surname )
VALUES 
  ((SELECT MAX( customer_id )+1 FROM customers cust), 'sharath', 'rock')
```

Here the `customer_id` is generated at the time of persisting.

Comment: What is the reason you are not using autoincrementing column or a SEQUENCE?

Comment: Altering the table is not possible as of now due to business application dependency already running live.